# Build a web service in ASP.NET / C# / Linq-to-SQL

Tags: c#, web-services, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to build a simple web service which return a list of shows from a database.
The web service has the following code to get its data:

```
private BLLoptredens BLLoptredens = new BLLoptredens();

[WebMethod]
public Array getVoorstellingenByArtiest(string p_artiest)
{
    return BLLoptredens.selectByArtistName(p_artiest).ToArray() ;
}
```

The data comes from the BLL, which just passes data from the DAL like so:

```
public IList<Optreden> selectByArtistName(string p_artiest)
{
   var query = (from o in dc.Optredens
                where o.artiest.Contains(p_artiest)
                select o);
   return query.ToList();
}
```

This crashes with the following error:

> You must implement a default accessor on System.Array because it
> inherits from ICollection

Can something help me on my way with this?

Comment: do not return an Array from the webmethod.you can return an array like Optreden[] if Optreden is serializable instead.

Comment: I get an iList<Optreden> from my DAL. How can I convert that to Optreden[]?

Comment: I think the ToArray can do the job, instead of the ToList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any particular need to give back an interface instead of a full-fledged generic class?

Try changing`IList<Optreden>`  to `List<Optreden>` -- that should do it.

Comment: that works! Thanks a lot. Is there a reason why I should still use iList instead of List in my code? Otherwise List seems like a more flexible solution?

Comment: List<> gives you the full class, where IList<> allows you to give back something that is basically not a List<>, but implements a similar behavior. Since you have a LIst<> already in your method there is no advantage of giving back just an interface.

Answer (score 0):

try public List instead of public IList

Answer (score 0):

```
public Optreden[] getVoorstellingenByArtiest(string p_artiest)
{
    return BLLoptredens.selectByArtistName(p_artiest).ToArray() ;
}
```

Note the Optreden[]. And I hope the Optreden is a DataContract with serializable members decorated with DataMember attribute